# Is there any solution to replicate multiple Active Directories to the one as a Proxy Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, replication, adam, adlds

We have multiple Active Directories in our company, such as :

```
finance-dc1.company.com
finance-dc2.company.com

sale-dc1.company.com
sale-dc2.company.com

development-dc1.company.com
development-dc2.company.com

...
```

Our development team want to authenticate (bind) and search users against one AD and not multiple ADs, so is there any solution to have a replica of all ADs into one AD (e.g: `proxy-dc.company.com`)?

Comment: Are all of the domains part of the same AD forest? If you don't know, you can check. From a computer joined to any of those domains, open PowerShell and run: `[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest().Domains | Select Name` - are all of those domains listed?

Comment: Yes there is only one forest

Comment: You could just read from the global catalog then. It's done exactly the same way, except via port 3268 (or 3269 for encryption).